# Как создать оператор += для Point c++

Tags: c++

Нужно создать такой оператор
Point& operator+=(Point &, const Point&)

Comment: В "вопросе" вижу констатацию факта. Не вижу вопроса. В чем ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Point
{
    double x,y;
};

Point& operator +=(Point&p, const Point& d)
{
    p.x += d.x;
    p.y += d.y;
    return p;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Point a{5,6};
    Point b{7,8};
    a += b;
    cout << a.x << "  " << a.y << endl;
}
```